# Cómo guardar números aleatorios en un array

Tags: c#, array, random, contador

En un programa que genera 50 números aleatorios y te saca cuantas veces sale 1, lo que quiero hacer es que el valor del `random` me lo guarde en el array `valor` y no sé cómo hacerlo.

No sé si directamente es valor `i = i` o tengo que darle el valor al `i` del `random` y al hacer eso me da error y no sé cómo seguir hacia adelante.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int[] valor = new int[50];

int contador = 0;
rnd.Next(0, 50);

for (int i = 0; i < valor.Length; i++)
{
    //valor[i] = rnd; o
    rnd = i; /*+*/ valor[i]=i;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        contador++;
    }   
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> Lo que quiero hacer es que el valor del random me lo guarde en el array

Pues adelante:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valor.Length; i++)
{
    valor[i] = rnd.Next(0, 50);
}
```

Aunque yo personalmente usaría Linq:

```
Random rand = new Random();
// Generar números.
var aleatorios = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 50).Select(indice => rand.Next(0, 50));
// Contar cuántos 1 hay.
Console.WriteLine(aleatorios.Count(numero => numero == 1));
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4/T8NADMXn3KfweJHgVIZOUVgqNqhQO3RADOZiRSclZ2pfClXVzx7cogom/3nv/eyo95GF5nnSlHvYHrXQ2Lj/U3hOed84FwdUhVfhXnB0J1dpwZIiHDh18IIpey1isbd3QOm1dpV5qg3mjkcQK9BCpi/43fi6MfWAAjgQFpbEaoanPI0k@DFQ2NCnCX5xB8tFHbY0UCw@5S5FgvbxSgxr@r45jGfAFWdlC@8kFbLHyf/hw4qnXPz1Al8Qt66Fh0u8OrvzPP8A)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

yo estoy aprendiendo también y espero haber entendido lo que solicitas. Ésto lo hice así.

```
int[] array = new int[50]
int RepUno = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
  array[i] = rnd.Next(0,50)
  Console.Write(array[i] + " ");
  
  if (array[i] == 1)
      RepUno++;
}

Console.Write("\nEl valor 1 se repite: " + RepUno + " veces");
```